# How do I do the same in pure JS and PHP, similar to jQuery and Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I started learning the Web, after a little language learning, I went straight to libraries and frameworks. Now I want to learn some native JS and PHP.

The question is as follows: on jQuery and Laravel, with an ajax request, I could simultaneously insert data into different html tags like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.basket-prod-name').html(response.name);
    $('.modal_order').attr('data-id', response.modalProdId);
    $('.basketimg').attr('src', response.img);
    $('input[name=inputModal]').val(1);
}
```

Then, in the controller, insert data there as follows:

```
return response()->json([ 
    'modalProdId'=> $product->id,
    'name'=> $product->name,
    'img'=> "/img/products/".$product->cardImage->path,
]);
```

But trying to do the same in pure JS and PHP fails. For example XMLHttpRequest, I can use responseText, then send a response from PHP(echo "something"), but what if I want to send data from PHP in several html tags? There are similar answers on SO, but it's kind of complicated, isn't there a simple documented way?

Comment: "Fails" is pretty broad. Please share your attempts, and your ways to debug **why** your code does not work

Comment: I described what I did, does it make sense to show my code? If you insist, I can add, but @Luke understood my question correctly and gave a comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very intermediate level, you can do a couple of things to acheive similar in "vanilla" JS and "framework free" PHP.

You want to JSON encode your data, before you send it back to the client.

product.php

```
<?php
$product->id = "PDX-123";
$product->name = "Product 123";

$jsonResponse = json_encode($product);

echo $jsonResponse;
?>
```

HTML

```
<h2>Get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo_2"></p>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    product = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = product.id;
    document.getElementById("demo_2").innerHTML = product.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "product.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: But, for example, if I have 2 tags `<p id="demo"></p>` and `<p id="demo_2"></p>`, and I want to inset 2 different data into them? For example, in `id="demo"` I want to insert `id` and in `id="demo_2"` I want to insert `name`?

Comment: I'll update with a more detailed example, but effectively you just repeat this line document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = product.name; with the id and assigned value changed